# How to find out if base class of Exception is OperationCanceledException?

Tags: c#, inheritance, exception, xamarin.forms

I get a `TaskCanceledException`:

[image: TaskCanceledException]

Then I pass this exception as `Exception` to another method. If I check for the type

```
if (ex.GetType() == typeof(OperationCanceledException))
    // ...
```

he doesn't step into this if clause. How can I check if the base type of the exception is `OperationCanceledException`?

`GetType()` only works for `TaskCanceledException`.
`GetType().BaseType` is not available here, neither is `IsSubclassOf()`. And I'm not in the `try-catch` anymore.

Comment: `ex is OperationCanceledException` should work

Comment: have you tried simply `if ( ex is OperationCanceldException )` ? You can even cast it in one statement: `if ( ex is OperationCanceldException ocex)`

Comment: Type.BaseType might be what you need. This property return the type from which your object is the child of.

Comment: @Fildor: Nope. Seems to work. Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have various possiblities:

- the [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.110).aspx) operator:

  ```
  if (ex is OperationCancelledException)
  ```
- the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.71).aspx) operator (if you want to use the exception further):

  ```
  OperationCancelledException opce = ex as OperationCancelledException;
  if (opce != null) // will be null if it's not an OperationCancelledException
  ```
- reflection with [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) (comments say doesn't work in Xamarin, though):

  ```
  if (typeof(OperationCancelledException).IsAssignableFrom(ex.GetType())
  ```

---

In C#7 you can do pattern matching:

```
if (ex is OperationCancelledException opce)
{
    // you can use opce here
}
```

Comment: Except of `IsAssignableFrom` the rest should work in `Xamarin.Forms`.

Answer (score 3):

`ex is OperationCanceledException` is the best option.

But if you really need reflection/type object, try this:

`typeof(OperationCanceledException).IsAssignableFrom(ex.GetType())`

[Type.IsAssignableFrom on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sadly `IsAssignableFrom` seems not to be available in `Xamarin.Forms` ...

Comment: or try `ex.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom` in Xamarin context

Comment: `is` is working fine, haven't tried `as` yet, but I think that will work too.

Comment: `GetTypeInfo()` is also not available, but thanks for the hint. For others not using XF this will work.